# How I can sort function be parameterized?

Tags: sorting, angular, reference

I have question, I would like to use obj.sort function like below where the object I want to sort can be referenced by global variable. However, I would like to define this function general way like second function so that I can call it whenever I need it. I do not know well how I can accomplish it. I do not think I can use "if(a.[field] < b.[field])". If someone has some idea about it, could you give some advice for it?

```
sortA() {
        this.A.sort(function(a, b) {
            if(a.name < b.name) return -1;
            if(a.name > b.name) return 1;
            return 0;
         });
    }

sort(A:Array<any>, field:string ) {
        A.sort(function(a, b) {
            if(a.[field] < b.[field]) return -1;
            if(a.[field] > b.[field]) return 1;
            return 0;
         });
    }
```